# powershell double for loop

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Need advice on loop
$Variable contains 11111  22222

```
foreach ($variable in $value) {
             for ([byte]$c = [char]'b'; $c -le [char]'c'; $c++) {
                    $variable."([char]$c)" } }
```

I am looking output as 11111b and then 22222c but currently, I am getting 11111b , 11111c and then 22222b and then 22222c.
Kindly advice

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Is it for a homework assignment?

Comment: Yes, it's a home assignment !!!

Comment: You really should ask your instructor for help. Getting someone to do your work for you might be considered cheating.

Comment: It's like my office assignment and it's a small part of it ...

Comment: @Bill_Stewart do I need to use break; after first loop end?

Comment: Thanks I have updated the question ... It's very confusing as how to add alphabets in series to the variable values.I am unable to find any example on net ..:(

Comment: It's the same problem as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25191803/powershell-cli-foreach-loop-with-multiple-arrays - stepping through two collections (values and characters) at the same time, pairing them up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you mean that `$value`, not `$variable`, contains `11111` and `22222`, specifically in an array.

Since you want `$c` to maintain its value between iterations of the `foreach` loop you need to initialize `$c` outside of the `foreach` loop.  Therefore, you really don't need (or, rather, should not use) two loops at all.

```
$value = 11111, 22222;
[Byte] $c = [Char] 'b';

foreach ($variable in $value)
{
    "$variable$([Char] $c++)"
}
```

This gives the output you are seeking:

```
11111b
22222c
```